# Javascript get value from popup input radio class

Tags: javascript, html, class

Is there any possible way to get an input radio value information (externaly), from a class?

I did a million attempts...

Here is the code im stucked to:

**Parent.htm**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
            <input type="text" id="txtName" readonly="readonly" />
            <input type="button" value="Select Name" onclick="SelectName()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var popup;
    function SelectName() {
        popup = window.open("Popup.htm", "Popup", "width=300,height=100");
        popup.focus();
        return false
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the page that i can't define to get the information that are on value.

**Popup.htm**

```
<html>
<body>
<form class="ddlNames">
<input type="radio" name="ddlNames" id="num" value="one">
<input type="radio" name="ddlNames" id="num" value="two">
<input type="radio" name="ddlNames" id="num" value="three">
</form>
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Select" onclick="SetName();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetName() {
        if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
            var txtName = window.opener.document.getElementById("txtName");
            txtName.value = document.getElementsByClassName("ddlNames")[0].value;
        }
        window.close();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried this way too:

```
<input type="radio" class="ddlNames" name="ddlNames" id="num" value="one">
<input type="radio" class="ddlNames" name="ddlNames" id="num" value="two">
<input type="radio" class="ddlNames" name="ddlNames" id="num" value="three">
```

To give each one the `ddlNames` class, but it's not working?

Comment: Sorry, my question may attracts more askers, because of the title.
I didn't found the post that you've sent me, may this post will help others to find easier for a solution. Hope you will understand me, all the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the checked value using a query-selector

```
document.querySelector('input[name="ddlNames"]:checked').value;
```

Comment: hmmm so you mean, to not use the class, just the name with ddlNames in it :/ lets try

Comment: Omg you saved my work, i had to create 5 popups pages, just because of this. Thanks a lot ^^